# Ionic popup radio buttons

Tags: ionic-framework, radio-button, popup

I would like to implement `$ionicPopup` with radio buttons. However, what I tried doesn't work as expected. I should have 3 options to choose, so if I choose option '1' and press 'Yes', I would like the console log to print out '1'...so far I can't seem to connect the radio buttons with it's equivalent scope variable in controller.

How can I reflect changes from radio button partial that loads in ionic popup?

In controller:

```
$ionicPopup.confirm({
                    templateUrl: 'templates/partials/orderPopup.html',
                    title: 'XYZ?',
                    scope: $scope,
                    buttons: [{
                        text: 'Yes',
                        type: 'button-positive',
                        onTap: function (e) {
                            console.log($scope.choice);
                        }
                    }, {
                        text: 'No',
                        type: 'button-default',
                        onTap: function (e) {
                            $state.go('shoppingCart');
                        }
                    }]
                })
```

And in view:

```
<ion-list ng-controller="shoppingCartCtrl">
    <style>
        .wrapping-list .item-content, .wrapping-list .item {
            overflow: initial;
            white-space: initial;
        }
    </style>
    <ion-radio class="wrapping-list" ng-model="choice" ng-value="'1'">Option1</ion-radio>
    <ion-radio class="wrapping-list" ng-model="choice" ng-value="'2'">Option2</ion-radio>
    <ion-radio class="wrapping-list" ng-model="choice" ng-value="'3'">Option3</ion-radio>
</ion-list>
```

If I make a `$scope.choice = 2` before the popup call, then I can see the option 2 being selected as a default, however, upon clicking any other option and then clicking OK, console returns 2

Comment: The expected behaviour is not clear

Comment: I've edited it...is it clear now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with `ng-model`. The 2-way binding in angular works when he model is an object which can be `updated via reference` from view as well as controller. So if you change your model as below, your code will work:

**Controller**

```
$scope.choice = {
  value: '2'
};
```

**HTML**:

```
<ion-radio class="wrapping-list" ng-model="choice.value" ng-value="'1'">
  Option1
</ion-radio>
<ion-radio class="wrapping-list" ng-model="choice.value" ng-value="'2'">
  Option2 
</ion-radio>
<ion-radio class="wrapping-list" ng-model="choice.value" ng-value="'3'">
  Option3
</ion-radio>
```

I have created a codepen to demonstrate the working code here: http://codepen.io/addi90/pen/aNroNN?editors=1010

Comment: For my problem, I had forgotten to put single quotes in value.